# What is the overall probability of two false results for the permutations of two binary tests

Tags: probability, hypothesis-testing

Graduate statistics was 30 years ago, I'm a bit rusty...Looking to determine the probably of all false results when taking two rapid covid tests (2 false positives, 2 false negatives, false negative/false positive, false positive/false negative) when True Positive rate is 84% and True Negative is 98.5%. Looking to determine how likely it is to get two false tests in all possible results.

Comment: An important caveat is the need to assume the test results are independent.  (They probably are not.)

Comment: I am assuming all things being equal and one person's results rather than the population as a whole. The rates posted above where determined in the study by comparing rapid test results with the gold standard test for accuracy of the rapid test results in a very large sample. I'm struggling with the concept of independence,  I vaguely recall it changing the formula, but can't recall how. The formula I've been using is (FP*FP)+(FN*FP)+(FN*FP)*(FN*FN) is that a correct formula if the are independent? What would be the formula lack of independence?  Why would two covid tests not be independent?

Comment: Two tests could fail to be independent whenever there is a common underlying cause influencing their results.  These could include misapplication of the test by the user; an underlying health condition or genetic characteristic that confuses the test; use of bad test media from the same batch; *etc.* *etc.* These would induce positive associations between the test-retest results.  Another possible explanation is that someone conducting a re-test might take more care than before, becoming more accurate the second time: this could induce a *negative* association between the results.